# Empty insights data for Graph API Explorer and API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

We are trying to get data about our page like "page_fans" but we always receive an empty data with call API and "Graph API Explorer".

This page has 3500 "total page likes", and 3400 "total page follow"

For example in "Graph API Explorer" with url : "/mypage/insights/page_fans"

```
The API respond :
{
  "data": [
  ],
  "paging": {...  }
}
```

We make tests with an admin site user.

Public data seems to be OK. In "Graph API Explorer" with url : "/mypage/insights/page_fans_country" we get

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "page_fans_country",
      "period": "lifetime",
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            "BE": ...,
```

The token we use has required scopes, in particular "read_insights". We’ve tried a lot of scopes ... with same result.

Example of token use in Graph API Explorer
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

```
Access Token    : Info
Valid           : True
Scopes          : ads_read, read_insights, manage_pages, business_management, read_audience_network_insights, public_profile
```

Our goal is to use API call (and getting all insight data) in our application with url like "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/mypage/insights/page_fans". 
But we don’t manage to have results with both API call and “Graph API Explorer”.

Could anyone help us ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to use a page access token? Have you read the documentation for that endpoint that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi WizKid, in "Graph API Explorer" I use the "Get User Access Token" which give me a good token. (he contains read_insights, I also give manage_pages)

But I think that "Page access token" is not necessary for me, because I’m the admin of my page. 
"/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/insights - section Permissions."
"A user access token with read_insights permission can retrieve metrics for all pages and domains owned by this user." 

However, I try with "Page access token" in “Graph API explorer” but “data” is still empty
Actually, this EndPoint returns only publicly available metrics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found my problem.
Despite the fact that I thought I was the administrator of my page, it was not.

Check this here :
https://www.facebook.com/My_Page/settings/?tab=admin_roles

I don't remember if this page is accessible if you are not admin of the page.

It is regrettable not to have a clear message in facebook response ;)

Comment: So, when you are not the admin of the page, the response its simply an empty data in the array? I am testing with some pages i am not the administrator and the only data i managed to get is with the page_fans_country and page_storytellers_by_country metrics, the documentations says that
`Any valid access token can be used for publicly available metrics (currently page_fans_country or page_storytellers_by_country).`